# Rerouting http traffic in ASP.NET application

Tags: asp.net, .net, http, reroute

I would like to re-route traffic in HTTP request from one server to another in an ASP.NET web site. I have been looking into trying to do this using an http module or http handler. Are these viable options for my case or does anyone have a better recommendation? This application is using .NET 4.0 Framework and is host on IIS6.

Comment: Take a look at using an HTTPModule with http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.rewritepath(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the comment above, I wanted to provide a small snippet of code.  You should be able to do this in your HTTPModule with Response.Redirect.  I am not 100% certain but I believe that the RewritePath method may throw a platform not supported exception on IIS6.  IIS6 definitely support Response.Redirect fortunately.

Go ahead a handler for begin request:

```
{
      context.BeginRequest += new EventHandler(MyBeginRequestMethod);
}
```

Then in your begin request method:

```
HttpApplication application = (HttpApplication)sender;
HttpContext context = application.Context;

if(context.Request.FilePath.Contains("someresource"))
{
     context.Response.Redirect("http://www.google.com");
}
```

Obviously you will be able to do some more comprehensive look-up of content and a more complete redirect this way.